# How can I deploy installed software setup one distribution to another

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I have a Ubuntu system with manually installed packages, obtained from a variety of sources such as apt repositories, snaps, and standalone packages. I'd like to distribute my list of software to others in a simple and convenient way, potentially using a Git repository. Primarily Ubuntu to Ubuntu but maybe also across distributions.

However, the struggle I face is that some of these packages require adding specific apt repositories, while others are snaps, and still others are available in the default apt repositories. A shell script seems inefficient. What's the best way to distribute my software list to others in a manageable way? Is this a use case for Nix Package Manager?

Comment: what about a shell script seems unappealing to you?

Comment: `I'd like to distribute my list of software to others` .. you mean others running the SAME setup you have?  The reason for all of this who-ha is because every flavor or libc, kernel, or damn near anything else requires a different compile.  Please define "others".

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why “A shell script seems inefficient.” It seems to do the work in my opinion, you just have to keep track of what you want to share in your script.

1. install default repositories packages
2. install packages from other repositories

   1. ensure the source is configured
   2. install the packages
3. install standalone packages

   1. download the package
   2. check the download
   3. install it

Of course, do all those both for Apt and Snap and fix version when needed.
You may also have a look at Ansible/Chef/Puppet/etc. It's up to you.